# How to make an inset in a figure

Tags: floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Image inside another image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89776/image-inside-another-image)

How can I have an inset (smaller picture) within a larger picture in LaTeX? is there any function for this or do I have to combine the pictures beforehand.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) No need to add thanks, upvoting good answers is the prefered way to do this.

Comment: could definitely be done using TikZ.

Comment: I've just posted a `tikz` solution in @cgnieder's link- I would call this a duplicate.

Comment: which link please?

Comment: I have found that overpic package is actually what I want