# Positioning inset image using overlap

Tags: floats, positioning

I recently read the post about insets ([Image inside another image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89776/image-inside-another-image)) and am trying to implement the method that uses overlaps. I can get the inset to appear, but I can't figure out how to position it. My LaTeX looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{figure2_2.eps}\llap{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{inset_f2_cropped.pdf}}
\caption{words}
\label{f2}
\end{figure}
```

The inset shows up in the lower left, mostly outside of the actual figure; I am a relatively new user, so if this is just the result of misinterpreting the original answer, I'm sorry!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89776/image-inside-another-image/120446#120446.  By using negative offsets, you can get the images to overlap, rather than inset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use picture mode coordinates.

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{figure2_2.eps}%
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(-10,-10){\includegraphics[height=2cm]{inset_f2_cropped.pdf}}
\end{picture}
\caption{words}
\label{f2}
\end{figure}
```

The first image will determine the space left for the figure, the second figure takes up no space (because the `picture` size is `(0,0)` but by adjusting the `(-10,-10)` coordinate you can position the second figure at any point over the first.  (I removed the `[h]` option to figure, if you use the option at all you should almost always include at least `t` and `p`)