# LaTeX - place more than one small pictures on top of a big one

Tags: graphics, rotating

I've been trying to put several small images on top of a large one.

One way I found to place one picture on top of another one was to use the `stackengine` package. I couldn't figure how to place several of them on the same figure though. What I tried was something like this bellow:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,epsfig} 
\usepackage{graphicx}     
\usepackage{stackengine}
\parskip 1em

\begin{document}

def\big{\includegraphics[width=0.99\textwidth]{Re80ro40mu50}}
def\little1{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{image0001}
def\little2{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{image0004}}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\bottominset{\little1}{\big}{0.25\textwidth}{0.17\textwidth}
\topinset{\little}{\big}{2cm}{3cm}
\bottominset{\little2}{\big}{0.25\textwidth}{0.17\textwidth}\par
\def\stackalignment{r}
\topinset{\little}{\big}{2cm}{1cm}
\bottominset{\little}{\big}{1cm}{2cm}

\end{document}
```

But what it does is it makes 4 figures, and places the small figure differently in each (instead of putting them on the same).

Another way I tried was to use boxes, like bellow:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,epsfig} 
\usepackage{graphicx}     
\usepackage{stackengine}
\parskip 1em

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.99\textwidth]{Re80ro40mu50}}
\includegraphics[width=0.99\textwidth]{Re80ro40mu50}\llap{\makebox[0.85\wd1][l]{\raisebox{3.4cm}{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{image0001}}}}\llap{\makebox[0.7\wd1][l]{\raisebox{3.8cm}{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{image0004}}}}\llap{\makebox[0.53\wd1][l]{\raisebox{5cm}{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{image0008}}}}\llap{\makebox[0.4\wd1][l]{\raisebox{9cm}{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{image0011}}}}\llap{\makebox[0.3\wd1][l]{\raisebox{2.8cm}{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{image0014}}}}
\caption{Drag coefficient history during the deformation of the droplet}
\end{figure}nter code here

\end{document}
```

This one actually works, but if want to rotate the whole image by adding `angle=270` in the `\includegraphics` options, so that I get a full-page image in large, it gives an error and complains about the options for `graphics` package. (Angle option works without adding the small images on top, so if it's just one picture.)

I would be really greatful if someone could tell me why I cannot rotate the images in the 2nd version, or how can I add all small images to the big one in the same figure. (Or any ways to add more than one small images /also rotated/ to one big rotated image!)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site! I think that [Image inside another image](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89776) covers your question

Answer (score 6):

A sideways house (my own artwork!) with two smaller houses on top.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}



\begin{figure}

\begin{picture}(200,200)

\put(50,50){\includegraphics[angle=90]{house}}

\put(175,200){\includegraphics[scale=.25]{house}}

\put(100,80){\includegraphics[scale=.25]{house}}

\end{picture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Gotta love that house! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the latest version of `stackengine`, currently V3.21.  It has been evolving rapidly.  One such area is on making nested insets easier.  While `\bottominset` and `\topinset` are still supported, their functionality has been taken over with `\stackinset`.

The syntax is

```
\stackinset{H-origin}{H offset}{V origin}{V offset}{inset material}{anchor material}
```

`H-origin` is either `l`, `c`, or `r`

`H offset` is a length

`V-origin` is either `t`, `c`, or `b`

`V offset` is a length

`inset material` is what you want to overlay (can be text or an image)

`anchor material` is the base object over which to overlay (can be text or an image)

From the stackengine documentation:

[image]