# Graph Labeling and Text Overlay Ability

Tags: pgfplots

I have a couple of question in regards to LaTeX ability to overlay text on a graph at a specific point. The background: I have a time-series plot that I load in to LaTeX using a txt file and the `pgfplots` package.

1. Is it possible to display the y-coordinate for a selected few x-coordinates in a graph and not for any other x-coordinates?
2. Is it possible to display and overlay text , above the plot-line, at a given x-coordinate?
3. If the second question is not possible, then how could I overlay text on top of a graph at a given part of the graph, not necessarily at a specific x-coordinate observation.

Comment: Please include a Minimal Working Example. All questions should include a small complete document people can compile to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Related questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12207/ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88404/

Comment: As far as item #3, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142828/latex-place-more-than-one-small-pictures-on-top-of-a-big-one/142839#142839 for insetting text and/or figures atop a base image.