# How to include hand-drawn pictures?

Tags: graphics

I'm well aware that this is borderline off-topic, but does anyone know how authors include (apparently) hand-drawn pictures in their books, such as this one from a programming textbook:

[image]

Such pictures seem to be too perfect to be made by hand, and show no sign of having been scanned. But I cannot imagine doing this with TikZ or Inkscape or any other drawing tool.

Comment: You can create graphics in any graphics program you'd like and include them in documents in the normal fashion. Even if hand drawn, nothing stops the artist from using a graphics tablet to do the drawing.

Comment: Maybe a picture made with a drawing software, incorporated with `\includegraphics`?

Comment: An intresting [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74878/124842) with a related topic. Maybe it will help.

Comment: you could see the [example code here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142828/latex-place-more-than-one-small-pictures-on-top-of-a-big-one/142834#142834) although hard to believe those diagrams were hand drawn, not precision coded in tikz

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/how-do-i-make-my-document-look-like-it-was-written-by-a-cthulhu-worshipping-madm

Comment: Drawing something like that by hand doesn't require "artistic talent" so much as "lots of practice". You could then scan it and use software like Inkscape to automatically trace the lines (to whatever level of accuracy you want), and convert the image from a raster scan into a scaleable vector form.

Comment: With professional scanning and printing equipment working at a "genuine" 2400 dots per inch or even higher (9600 DPI is perfectly possible, if you need that much resolution) any rasterizing artefacts are completely invisible to the naked eye. At those resolutions, the diffusion of the ink into the paper smooths out the "bumps" in the rasterizing, which doesn't happen at 300 or 600 DPI.