# Figure inset in right bottom corner - non transparent

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning

I have 2 pdf images: 1.pdf and 2.pdf.
Now I would like to have 2.pdf as an inset (in the right bottom corner) in the Figure  1.pdf.

My question is almost similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89776/image-inside-another-image) ; however I only want 1 image with 1 inset figure.

Furthermore, when I tried to alter some of the TeX code, I obtained a transparent figure inset of 2.pdf in the image 1.pdf, and I don't want this.

It would even be fine if there would be a white box around the inset of 2.pdf.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues, it would appear from the OP's comments: 1) insetting an image, and 2) eliminating/masking the transparancy of the inset.  I will address the issues in turn:

**IMAGE INSET**

Here I give two examples using `\stackinset`.  The first flush to the bottom right corner, and the second with some border.  I use `\includegraphics` for the images, but `tikz` code or similar things can go in their place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent\stackinset{r}{}{b}{}{\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-A}}
  {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-B}}\medskip

\noindent\stackinset{r}{15pt}{b}{25pt}{\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-A}}
  {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-B}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a version with a white border:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\fboxrule=5pt\relax
\fboxsep=0pt\relax
\noindent\stackinset{r}{}{b}{}
  {\color{white}\fbox{\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-A}}}
  {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-B}}\medskip
\end{document}
```

[image]

**MASKING INSET TRANSPARANCY**

To deal with a transparent inset image-A, place it on a white `\colorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\fboxrule=5pt\relax
\fboxsep=0pt\relax
\noindent\stackinset{r}{}{b}{}
  {\colorbox{white}{\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-A}}}
  {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-B}}\medskip
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I still have the transparency issue. Image A is transparent in my case and thus I cannot see it very well using this method. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: @student441 See my follow-up